# How can i pervent special character input to a php file?

Tags: php, html, iframe, special-characters

http://pastebin.com/Jti6DWU6 <--
This is a script in which there are 3 forms and i want to prevent special chars in the first field to prevent iFrame Injection...
I suck at programming
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What kind of "special" input? What have you attempted or used till now? Why not post relevant code *here*? (The form itself isn't relevant.)

Comment: by special char input i mean "<>/\ etc" to prevent xss/iframe attacks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `htmlspecialchars`, that's what that function is for.

[Check the manual](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Here's an example from the manual:

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

Just add the string to the 1st argument of the function. The 2nd will tell the function how to handle quotes. In the example above, it will convert both double and single quotes.

Comment: how can u tell me, where to add it and how?

Answer (score 0):

Classical protection that google could have provide you in a few seconds...

htmlspecialchars or htmlentities is the way to go.

- https://php.net/htmlspecialchars
- https://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: how can u tell me, where to add it and how?

Comment: Just call the function on the data you want to escape...